# pdb file ( visual studio )

Tags: .net, pdb-files

I want to send a debug executable to a client so I could replicate the crash by loading the pdb file. 
For this purpose, I created a debug build. Should I send both the executable and pdb to the client .

Please advise

Answer (score 0):

If client going to re-compile/compile @ their end and run the code then NO, that's not needed. Since already generated a debug build; once at client side they run the application in `debug` mode; same `pdb` file will get generated.

Else, YES; you will have to send the `pdb` file as well along with the `exe`.

But this `pdb` file will only have your `.NET` application related debug info. So, if the crash is due to some other environmental issue then that has to be captured separately.

Comment: The pdb file is created when the application is compiled, not at run-time. It contains information about line numbers, so if you want that in your stack trace you need to provide the pdb along with the exe.

Comment: Why?? If I just have the `.exe` and compile it in my machine, do you think the same `pdb` will not be generated? Try it once and see.

Comment: @Rahul The client is not compiling the exe, the OP is and sending the client the exe and the associated pdb.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain, Thanks for pointing but from OP's post it's not at all clear whether that's the case. Anyways, have updated answer to reflect that point as well.

Comment: Seemed pretty clear to both myself and Scott that he was sending an *executable* to the client, not the source code.